# SVN Branch Switch Picking Up New Files

Tags: eclipse, svn, switch-statement, branch, subclipse

I ran into this problem while using eclipse with Subclipse:

On Branch A. Files are F1 and F2. Create new file F3 and commit to Branch A. Switch to branch B and F3 is still in workspace. Accidentally commit F3 to Branch B.

I was told that switching between branches with different files is unsafe, and the correct protocol is to switch from Branch A -> trunk -> cleanup -> switch to Branch B. Is this correct? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

No, switching from A to B is safe and works for me, including deleting files that are present in one branch but not the other.

However - SVN will not delete unversioned files, and I'm not sure about modified files. So if file F3 was modified after commit, SVN will not delete it as it has changes it think you probably want to keep. It will merge these changes into the new working copy (though in this case, I would have thought you'd get a conflict or error message)

Did you add the file, but not commit it? This is the most likely cause.